# How do I connect development-stage Django web app to an existing AWS MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services

Short question - How do I connect to an existing Amazon Web Services MySQL database from my development-stage Django web app?

Context:

I am working on creating a webpage using the Django framework.

I've successfully created an AWS MySQL RDS database and have imported my data and connected to it successfully via MySQL Workbench.

I am now at a point where I am trying to connect to the database from my Django app.  I will require read-only functionality from the database from within the app... I will not be writing any new info to the database.  Furthermore, I am trying to do this within a development environment, as I am not even close to anything production worthy (ie, I am working locally off of my laptop).

I've added the AWS database information to my Django settings.py file, and based on my research, to generate the requisite models I'll need to utilize Django's 'inspectdb' utility.  I've tried that, and the resulting error received was:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user '[**my username was here, which actually showed my literal first name rather than any type of username that was established by AWS**]'@'pool-[**my IP address was here**].nwrknj.fios.verizon.net'

Has anyone else experienced this issue and identified a solution?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    '[removed]': {
          'NAME': '[removed]',
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'USERNAME': '[removed]',
          'PASSWORD': '[removed]',
          'HOST': '[removed].us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
          'PORT': '3306'
```

Comment: Can you put an anoymised version of your database settings so we can check?

Comment: Certainly, please see below (sorry, not sure how to format the settings within the comment field):

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    '[removed]': {
          'NAME': '[removed]',
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'USERNAME': '[removed]',
          'PASSWORD': '[removed]',
          'HOST': '[removed].us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
          'PORT': '3306'

Comment: Update - I've added the DB settings to the original question, rather than posting in the comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have `DATABASE_ROUTERS` set to use an alternate database, everything in Django will use the `default` database. Get rid of the current ENGINE and NAME in default and move all the `[removed]` db info into `default`.

Also make sure that the AWS RDS port 3306 is open to your FIOS IP address. Ideally you would restrict it in AWS to only the actual servers (whether on AWS or elsewhere) but for now you may have to set a broad IP range to allow for your FIOS IP changing periodically during development.

Comment: Quite the opposite. You only need Routers if you actually have MULTIPLE databases within your Django application. If you only have one database, as appears to be the case, just move the credentials to `default` and you should be all set.

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong syntax for specifying the database settings.  

I changed "USERNAME" to "USER" and everything worked like a charm.